# machine learning algorithms that can not apply map reduce model

Tags: mapreduce, machine-learning

The paper "Map-Reduce for Machine Learning on Multicore" shows 10 machine learning algorithms, which can benefit from map reduce model. The key point is "any algorithm fitting the Statistical Query Model may be written in a certain “summation form.”, and the algorithms can be expressed as summation form can apply map reduce programming model.

For those algorithms that could not be expressed as summation form do not mean that they can not apply map reduce model. Could anyone point out any specific machine learning algorithm, which can not speed up by map reduce model?

Comment: You can fit every algorithm into mapreduce, but that does not mean that they are working efficient.

Comment: Yes, I know we can apply map reduce to every algorithm, but it does not mean that we can speed up the performance for some algorithms. The paper I mentioned above lists 10 algorithms, and they showed how to transfer the original algorithms into so called "summation form". Then, we can apply map reduce technique to summation form. I would like to know which algorithm can not benefit from map reduce model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MapReduce does not work when there are computational dependencies in the data. This limitation makes it difficult to represent algorithms that operate on structured models.

> As a consequence, when confronted with large scale problems, we often abandon rich structured models in favor of overly simplistic methods that are amenable to the MapReduce abstraction [2](http://select.cs.cmu.edu/publications/paperdir/uai2010-low-gonzalez-kyrola-bickson-guestrin-hellerstein.pdf).

In Machine-learning community, numerous algorithms iteratively transform parameters during both learning and inference, e.g., Belief Propagation, Expectation Maximization, Gradient Descent and Gibbs Sampling. Those algorithms iteratively refine a set of parameters until some termination criteria is matched [2](http://select.cs.cmu.edu/publications/paperdir/uai2010-low-gonzalez-kyrola-bickson-guestrin-hellerstein.pdf).

If you invoke MapReduce in each iteration, yes, I think you still can speed up the computation. The point here is that we want a better abstraction framework so that it's possible to embrace the graphical structure of data, to express sophisticated scheduling or automatically assess termination.

BTW, [Graphlab](http://www.graphlab.org) is one of the alternatives motivated by the above reason [2](http://select.cs.cmu.edu/publications/paperdir/uai2010-low-gonzalez-kyrola-bickson-guestrin-hellerstein.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Therefore, BP, EM, GD and Gibbs Sampling can not benefit from map reduce model, right? As I know, the EM and batch gradient descent in the paper I listed above can benefit from map reduce. The authors said that stochastic gradient descent is not the case, even though GSD is often more efficient than GD on large scale problems.

Comment: Yes, I agree EM and batch GD can benefit from map/reduce. What I am trying to point out is sometimes whether or not we can benefit from map/reduce is not as important as having a better abstraction model. see my second last paragraph. Ability to speed up the algorithm does not mean it's the best model. We might be able to speed up significantly more by using another model.